# Return value of a for loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, for-loop, expression

I understand that, in Ruby, a for loop is an expression and therefore has a value which can be assigned to a variable. For example

```
x = for i in 0..3 do
end
```

sets `x` to `0..3` - the range over which the loop iterates.

Is the return value of a for loop always the range as above, or can it differ depending on the body of the loop?

Comment: Have you tried following any basic tutorials, such as [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm), and just seeing what you get?

Comment: Ruby provides a very good interactive shell (`irb`) to let you explore the language. Why not try it yourself?

Comment: It seems that, if the body includes a `break`, the value of the loop is `nil`. Is that the only other possible value for the loop? I don't know how to find out. Is this sort of thing documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is returned by the `for` loop is dependent on how the enumerator you are looping over is implemented. For example, let's implement our own enumerator.

```
chipmunks = Enumerator.new { |c|
    c << "Alvin"
    c << "Simon"
    c << "Theodore"
    "Dave"
}
```

Notice that the last thing in the Enumerator is the string "Dave". Now let's use this in a `.each` loop.

```
result = chipmunk.each do |chipmunk|
    puts chipmunk
end
#=> Alvin
#=> Simon
#=> Theodore

puts result
#=> Dave
```

My guess is that `Range` is implemented in such a way that its enumerator returns itself. By doing so, it gives you the ability to chain methods.

```
(1..100).each { |n| something(n) }.each {|y| something_else(y) }
```